# django on heroku: ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I don't run into any problems running my django app locally, but for some reason on heroku I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info` and have no idea how to fix this.

Here are my heroku logs:

```
    2014-07-07 18:45:45 [18423] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.13.4
    2014-07-07 18:45:45 [18424] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 456, in spawn_worker
        worker.init_process()
      File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
        self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
      File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
        self.callable = self.load()
      File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
        return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
      File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 241, in import_app
        __import__(module)
      File "/app/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
        from dj_static import Cling
      File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 7, in <module>
        from django.core.handlers.base import get_path_info
    ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info
    2014-07-07 18:45:45 [18424] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18424)
    18:45:46 web.1  | 2014-07-07 18:45:46 [18423] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    18:45:46 web.1  | 2014-07-07 18:45:46 [18423] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

My procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app.wsgi
```

and my app/wsgi.py file:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectname.settings")

Comment: that does nothing — still the same error

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if you feel it answers your question. You are under no obligation, however.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `dj-static==0.0.6` in your Virtualenv requirements.txt file. The Heroku Django tutorial currently shows 0.0.5. You might be running 0.0.6 locally but not in Heroku.

I've reported this issue to Heroku and their tutorial is now updated to reflect newer versions in the requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Try these 3 steps:

1. Install last version of dj-static (`pip install dj-static==0.0.6`).
2. Install the Heroku toolbet (`pip install django-toolbet`).
3. Be sure `requirements.txt` file is updated.